# change style of the workitem label

Tags: css, tfs, styles, label, workitem

I need to change the style/CSS of a TFS work item class. 
The main idea is to display the label field in a different color.

`$(".workitemcontrol-label").css("color", "blue");` really works from the browser console, but when I put the same as part of custom control it does not:

```
onLoaded: (args: WitExtensionContracts.IWorkItemLoadedArgs) => {
    $(".workitemcontrol-label").css("color", "blue");
},
```

The above code doesn't work. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I further figured it out that the labels were not getting loaded by the time onLoaded event is getting called. So the changes to css will not work. Is there a better place where I can add the code to change the css?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `.css` files of the TFS, they are located in (for TFS 2017, and the default theme):

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 15.0\Application Tier\Web Services\_static\tfs\Dev15.M125.1\App_Themes\Default
```

In the path above you will find 2 CSS files:

`WorkItemArea.css` and `WorkItemArea.min.css`

Open them, search the `.workitemcontrol-label` class and change the color.

*Recommended stopping the TFS service before the operation.*